# looking for good example/template for openid + oauth hybrid with python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, openid

I have implemented oauth and openid separately (that is, sign in with OpenId, separate authorization to Google Data API with OAuth) and would like to combine them.

Currently I have the following in my app.yaml

```
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: main.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
  login: required
```

Then, in main.py I have:
(imports removed for clarity)

```
def getClient():
    client =  gdata.calendar.service.CalendarService()
    consumer_key = 'my-app.appspot.com'
    consumer_secret = 'consumersecret'
    client.SetOAuthInputParameters(
        gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1,
        consumer_key=consumer_key, 
        consumer_secret=consumer_secret)
    gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(client)
    return client

class OAuthOne(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        client = getClient()
        request_token = client.FetchOAuthRequestToken(oauth_callback='http://my-app.appspot.com/oauth2')
        client.SetOAuthToken(request_token)
        auth_url = client.GenerateOAuthAuthorizationURL()
        self.redirect( auth_url )

class OAuthTwo(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        client = getClient()
        token_from_url = gdata.auth.OAuthTokenFromUrl(self.request.uri) 
        if not token_from_url:
            self.redirect('/oauth')
        else:
            client.SetOAuthToken(token_from_url)
            oauth_verifier = self.request.get('oauth_verifier', default_value='')
            client.UpgradeToOAuthAccessToken(oauth_verifier=oauth_verifier)
            self.redirect('/')

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.user = users.get_current_user()
        self.template_values = {}
        if self.user:
            # do calendar api stuff here
            self.template_file = 'templates/index.html'
        else:
            self.template_file = 'templates/denied.html'

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.template_file)
        self.response.out.write( template.render(path, self.template_values) )

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/oauth', OAuthOne),
                                  ('/oauth2', OAuthTwo),
                                  ('/_ah/login_required', OpenIDHandler),
                                  ('/', MainPage)],
                                 debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

also in main.py, from http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae.html

```
class OpenIDHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        """Begins the OpenID flow and begins Google Apps discovery for the supplied domain."""
        login_url = users.create_login_url(dest_url='http://my-app.appspot.com/',
                                             _auth_domain=None,
                                             federated_identity='gmail.com')
        self.redirect( login_url )
```

As for the hybrid protocol, there is a PHP example [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/hybrid/index.php), and a java example [here](http://code.google.com/p/step2/) but I cannot find anything for python.

I assume that the start of the magic will need to happen in my OpenIDHandler, and that I need to use something other than `users.create_login_url()`. Google's documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#settingup) tells me that I need to 'Create the mechanism for performing discovery and making authentication requests.' and 'Add OAuth capability to authentication requests' (more docs [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#oauth) ), but as far as I can tell, not how to do it. At least not with Python.

There is an example of a raw http request a little lower on [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://www.example.com/checkauth
&openid.realm=http://www.example.com
&openid.assoc_handle=ABSmpf6DNMw
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
&openid.oauth.consumer=www.example.com
&openid.oauth.scope=http://docs.google.com/feeds/+http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
```

But I'm not sure how to use this.

So apart from helping this become a shining example of a best practice, I really need to know how to 'Add OAuth capability to authentication requests'.

Comment: I have the same problem, I would like to use hybrid protocol in python but i have not found any example. Did you managed with it?. If yes, please post example of code.